# Run scripts at a specific time with powershell

Tags: powershell, task

I created a script file and I want this script to run at the time I set every day

I have used the following code for this operation but it does not work.

```
 $app = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\script.ps1";
 $time = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 22:58pm
 Register-ScheduledTask TEST1 -Action $app -Trigger $time;
```

How do I run **script.ps1** at a specific time every day?
Where did I make a mistake?
How can I solve my problem?

**NOTE**: my powershell version

```
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.407                                                                                                                                         
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                               
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                               
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.407                                                                                                                                        
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                   
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?  Does it give you an error or just it deos not run?  Did you check you log?

Comment: script doesn't work when I set time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple issues.  With the script itself, you did not provide the source.  There could be also issue with the rights (do you have rights to create a task?  Do you have rights to run the script from the destination?)

Anyways, from what you have posted the issue is that you are trying to run the script directly but you should `--execute powershell.exe` first and then run the script.

This is one way to have your powershell script scheduled (note that it is running with the highest possible priviliges):

```
$TaskName = 'MyScript'
$User= "domain\user"
$ScriptPath = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\script.ps1"

$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 22:58 -Daily 
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file $ScriptPath" 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

Comment: I've been dealing for 2 days, but I haven't been able to reach the solution.
as above, does not work when the clock changes as I want
also does not give any errors

Comment: `$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 10am -Daily 
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe"  -Argument "-executionpolicy bypass -NoExit -noprofile -file C:\Users\Liduma\Desktop\script.ps1" 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName MyScript -Trigger $Trigger -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest -Force`

Comment: I finally solved the problem.
I've made an add to your code as follows.

`$desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$scriptPath="$desktop\script.ps1";
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 10:56 -Daily 
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe"  -Argument "-executionpolicy bypass -NoExit -noprofile -file $scriptPath" 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName MyScript -Trigger $Trigger -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest -Force`

Comment: @HibritUsta I have tested my code and it work for me.  You probably do not have rights for the desktop folder or you have different location?  Anyways, I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: i am again
The script was working yesterday.
I'm running the script again.
What could be the problem?
Why does it work sometimes and sometimes doesn't work?
eg when I set the evening hours but it doesn't work when I set the morning hours

Comment: @HibritUsta you have to set the time (AM/PM) correctly.  Here the job was planned only at 22:58PM only

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna do it like you said. @tukan

Comment: Your time format is also whacked ... _-At 22:58_  **--OR--** _-At 10:58pm_  
.  
_22:58pm_ is not a valid time.

Comment: @boB good catch, it was already at the OP so I did not adjust it.  I'll fix it.